# On servo loops bandwidth and tracking

Tags: control-engineering

Referring to article https://www.controldesign.com/articles/2018/servo-terminology-makes-a-difference/

I was unable to understand how loop gain influences the noise rejection and tracking. Taking example of resolvers which is a type2 servo loop, how is relation established between tracking rate, bandwidth, resolution and excitation frequency. I guess that tracking rate and BW must be related.

Would be helpful if someone would clarify the term tracking rate  and what limits the tracking rate? ( Since tracking rate is a large signal phenomenon, the rise time is influenced by the loop delay parameters, which eventually does influence the BW)

Answer (score 1):

Tracking performance is a two-fold principle:

**Transient performance:**
The settling time and overshoot. This is where your bandwidth and phase margin play a role. The bandwidth affects the frequency of the response, thus in general, higher bandwidth means shorter rise time and faster response. But it can also oscillate for quite a while, which harms the settling time. The figure below shows the closed loop performance of a system with varying bandwidths, but they all have the same phase margin (45 degrees). Sidenote, I know most use the bandwidth for the first crossing of -3dB, but this plot uses 0dB as it is common in the region where I live and it is easier to compute a controller that achieves that exactly.
[image: Closed loop performance with varying bandwidths]

Phase margin affects how much the controller overshoots. Higher phase margins therefore result in faster response. The figure below shows the same system with various controllers with each a different phase margin at the bandwidth (20Hz). From this you can also note changing the phase margin does not affect the rise time.

[image: Closed loop performance with varying phase margins]

**Steady state performance:** This part of tracking performance shows how well a controller can actually track your signal. This is where disturbance attenuation and noise rejection play an important role. First of all, even in a perfect environment a poorly constructed controller might still not be able to track the reference with an error of 0 (this also depends on your system). This is due to the lack of an integrator action. If a system has a pure integrator (meaning a magnitude of +inf dB at 0 rad/s) the system will always reduce steady state error to 0. Even better, if a system has a double integrator, it can also perfectly track a ramp (so a constant velocity).

The sensitivity function plays an important role in assessing disturbance attenuation and noise rejection performance. This function (S = 1/(1+CH)) shows how well these phenomena are suppressed at which frequency. If a system has a pure integrator, the suppression will be approaching -inf at 0Hz (therefore completely ignoring the presence thereof). At the bandwidth, the sensitivity is also 0 dB and after it, the noise and disturbances play as much a role as the actual control signal, thus rendering your controller useless. There is also a principle in the sensitivity function known as the "waterbed effect", which roughly means that if you want to improve performance at some frequency, you are going to lose it somewhere else. Therefore if you increase your bandwidth, you might lose disturbance attenuation, or even closed loop stability.

Additionally, the controllers power source must be able to provide the energy your controller desires. if not, everything between loss of performance and loss of stability might occur.

To wrap it up, the encoder resolution has close to no influence on the dynamical performance of the system other than that it is not possible to reduce your error to less than 1 encoder step. The operating frequency of your (physical) controller is however a limiting factor, but that is usually over 20x higher than your desired bandwidth.

I hope this helped, if not please ask.

Comment: The answer was comprehensive. In relation to article from the link https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/75731446AN264.pdf?doc=CN0276.pdf. Could you explain the relation between tracking rate vs bandwidth vs resolution. I mean the article does provide explanations,without mathematical basis